# Following lines of code

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a program, or a native feature of Eclipse that allows for running a class in steps, each step being detailed (value of containers at that step, highlighting the line of code that is being executed at that step, etc).

Comment: are you looking for eclipse debugger?

Comment: Yes. If that's what is' called. I'm pretty sure that Eclipse has a debugger.  IS what I described in my OP what that does?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the debugger. No need to install additional plugin. See tutorial for example here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try Jive debugger. This was developed by my university.

http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive/

Comment: Thanks.  Is this a stand-alone IDE?  Or does it function only to debug in tandem with the IDE I am using?

Comment: It is a plug-in for eclipse